# Set application theme

Tags: android

I have made a simple app and when I deploy on my smartphone this has the background white and texts black but all native apps are with background black and texts white.

In manifest file I get:

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

How can I do for my app has the same theme that my samartphone?

Thanks.

Comment: can you write in better grammar ?

Comment: I´m so sorry, but mu english is very bad

Comment: https://www.google.com.au/search?q=changing+themes+in+android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@style/AppTheme` refers to a `style` resource in your `res/values`. Look there to see how it is defined. If it's the default as created by Eclipse ADT or Android Studio Wizard, there's probably the following in `res/values/styles.xml`:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
```

And then in `res/values-v11/styles.xml`:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
```

Change this to

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
```

to make the base theme Holo Light instead of Holo (Dark).

Answer (score 0):

You can select themes provided by Android by default or can create the one on your own.